# 404 in home page when open incognito Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, 404, redirect-url

I have an issue that I got 404 page when open the store in incognito mode but for the regular page in the browser it works fine because it is already cashed before.

Also when I tried to open any other page like categories or products page directly in incognito works fine, only the home page redirect to 404.

what could be the problem?, any help please.

Comment: Maybe the cookie domain in the core_config_data table is wrong?

Comment: Where can i change the domain in this table , can you clarify please